# Input button and ajax not submitting POST

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a pretty simple form. I am submitting with Ajax. The form works fine. However when I try to use php to check if an input button was pressed before I execute the code, It does not seem to pick up the button. 
Any advice on what to do would be great. I have added a sam[le of the code below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="Email-student" method= "post">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Email-subject" placeholder="Email Subject">  
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="Email-message" placeholder="Enter messages"></textarea>  
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Save Changes" />
</form> 

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Email-student').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = "mysql.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function(data) {
                    //$('.Email-student').html(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

        })
    })
</script>
```

This is a simplified version of my Php file

```
if (isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
    echo  'btnSubmit';
}
```

Comment: Does the request make it to the PHP page? Is the `POST` populated there? `print_r($_POST);` before the `isset`.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Your code would be signfiicantly easier to read if you indented things consistently.

Comment: Why don't you check for `if(isset($_POST['Email-subject']))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serialize()` will not include any submit buttons in the form. They are only successful controls if used to submit the form, and `serialize()`:

- isn't really part of the form submission process
- can't know which, if any, submit button was used to submit the form

Consequently, `isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])` will not be true.

Use some other mechanism to determine if there is form data that you are interested in (such as the existence of the `Email-subject` field).